# Woher kommt "Du daube Nuss"?

Tags: etymology

**German**

Wenn man eine Nuss knackt und diese leer ist, sagt man, das ist eine *daube Nuss* gewesen. Daher auch das Sprichwort "Du daube Nuss" (Später zu "taube Nuss" geworden), wenn jemand nichts in der Birne hat.

Jetzt frage ich mich, ist *daub* ein altdeutsches Wort für hohl?

---

**English**

If you crack a nut and nothing is inside, Germans say *Das war eine daube Nuss*. It's also a swearword when someone "has no brain" and acted stupid.

Now I'm wondering if *daub* is an old German word for empty/hollow.

Comment: Mir scheint: alternative Form von *taub*, das selber mehrere Bedeutungen hat und noch mehr hatte: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&bookref=21,162,43

Comment: DWDS und Duden haben keinen Eintrag für "daub". Richtig ist "eine taube Nuss". Das Adjektiv taub ist mehrdeutig.

Comment: "Daub" ist aus irgendeinem Dialekt.

Answer (score 7):

#### Taub

> adj. goth. daubs, ahd. toub doub, mhd. toup toub; altn. douf, mnd. dôf, altn. daufr, ags. deáf aus derselben wurzel wie tob (toben) und dumm.<sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&bookref=21,162,43)</sup>

Danach stammt *taub* aus dem gotischen *daubs*, das im Niederdeutschen *dôf* (vgl. doof), im Neuhochdeutschen "taub" und im Englischen *deaf* wurde.

Unter den zahlreichen Bedeutungen wohnte *taub* schon lange sowohl ein "hohler Körper" (taube Nuss) als auch "dumm" inne.

Siehe auch:

[DWDS: Etymologisches Wörterbuch](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=taub)

Comment: +1 für die gewagte (aber m.E. geglückte) Konstruktion um das "Innewohnen" einer Bedeutung herum :)

Answer (score 4):

daube kommt aus dem Schwäbischen !

Eine dabue Nuss (=taube Nuss) ist nicht schwerhörig, sondern sie ist in ihrer Schale vetrocknet. Ist ein Mensch eine daube Nuss, hört er zwar gut, ist aber hohl im Kopf. 
**Daub bedeutet unbrauchbar!**
Ist eine Suppe daub, muss man nachwürzen. Stadttauben scheinen das Fliegen auch schon verlernt zu haben. Deswegen:

> Dia daube Daube sẽnd dôch z'bleed zõm Fliaga !

Ich hoffe ich konnte dir damit helfen !